# Pass integer from jsp page to controller

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How can I pass the value of "i" as the index of list availableRooms from the jsp page to the controller.? i and availableRooms are there in given code.

I want to get the index of table row where I press the 'addRoom' button as the input to my controller where I am trying to add the object at passed index to another list and display in the Reservation Cart.
I tried this line of code in my controller

```
int index = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("roomPosition");
```

but I get index as 0 everytime

AvailableRooms.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="main.bean.HotelBean" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Rooms Available</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h3>Rooms Available</h3>
</center>
<form name="availableRooms" action="HotelReservationContoller" method="post">
<table border="1" align="center">
    <thead bgcolor="#FDE6B5">
        <font color="white">
        <tr>
            <td>Room Number</td>
            <td>Room Type</td>
            <td>Index</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </font>
    </thead>
    <%
      HotelBean rb;
        HttpSession newSession=request.getSession(false);
        ArrayList<HotelBean> availableRooms = (ArrayList<HotelBean>)session.getAttribute("availableRooms");
        Iterator<HotelBean> HotelBeanIterator = availableRooms.iterator();

        int i=0;
        while (HotelBeanIterator.hasNext())
        {   
             rb = (HotelBean) HotelBeanIterator.next();

              %>
        <tr>    
            <td><%= rb.getRoomNo()%></td>
            <td><%= rb.getRoomType()%></td>
            <td><%= i %>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="<%= i %>" name="roomPosition"/> <input type="submit" value="addRoom" name="button"></td> 
        </tr>
    <%
        i++;
        }
    %>  

</table>

 <%
if(newSession!=null)
{
    ArrayList<HotelBean> pickedRooms=null;

    pickedRooms=(ArrayList<HotelBean>)newSession.getAttribute("ReservationCart");

        newSession.setAttribute("ReservationCart",pickedRooms);
    %>
    <jsp:include page="ReserveCart.jsp" flush="true"/>
    <%}%> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are sending lot of parameters with the same name - roomPosition. May be you want to select a room and sent *this* position. Think in another way to do that.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev , in the 4th <td> tag , I am trying to set the value using value="<%= i%>" and am fetching this value in my controller, but in this jsp page [ value="<%= i%>"] this line of code is setting the value to 0 only instead of i .

Comment: Yes, I see that but the name of the hidden field is **always** roomPosition. How will you retreive the desired field in the controller? You are getting the first of all with value 0.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev by using the [value=<%= i%>] field of  input tag . as it is iterating I am increasing the value of i , wont it take the value of i ? Also in the third <td>tag I am printing out the value of i and it is giving the correct value but it isn't passing that value to the input tag? How can I get the index. Can you suggest some alternative?

Comment: You don't understand what I want to tell you. Your value of **i** is increased but the name of the field remains the same. In the controller when you do `request.getParameter("roomPosition")` you'll receive the first of the parameters in the request with the name *roomPosition*. **THIS** parameter, the first one, has value of 0. What I can suggest is to put a checkbox with value of *i*. Check the desired room. On submit event set the value of the checked room to a hidden field with name *checkedRoomPosition*. Ask for *checkedRoomPosition* in the controller.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Okok. thank you . Got your point after going through internet. :)